Google cloud build trigger with terraform gives Error creating Trigger: googleapi: Error 400: Request contains an invalid argument
I have a gen2 connection setup successfully, the only resource that I am unable to create is the trigger and I have searched all logs for. more informative description than this "error: Error creating Trigger: googleapi: Error 400: Request contains an invalid argument."
Below is my main.tf
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "~> 5.33.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "google" {
  project     = var.gcp_project_id
  region      = var.gcp_region
  credentials = "./key.json"
}

// Create a secret containing the personal access token and grant permissions to the Service Agent
resource "google_secret_manager_secret" "github_token_secret" {
  project   = var.gcp_project_id
  secret_id = "github_pat"

  replication {
    auto {}
  }
}

resource "google_secret_manager_secret_version" "github_token_secret_version" {
  secret      = google_secret_manager_secret.github_token_secret.id
  secret_data = var.git_secret_token_data
}

data "google_iam_policy" "serviceagent_secretAccessor" {
  binding {
    role    = "roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor"
    members = [var.gcp_iam_role_member]
  }
}

resource "google_secret_manager_secret_iam_policy" "policy" {
  project     = google_secret_manager_secret.github_token_secret.project
  secret_id   = google_secret_manager_secret.github_token_secret.secret_id
  policy_data = data.google_iam_policy.serviceagent_secretAccessor.policy_data
}

// Create the GitHub connection
resource "google_cloudbuildv2_connection" "github_connection" {
  project  = var.gcp_project_id
  location = var.gcp_region
  name     = "github_connection"

  github_config {
    app_installation_id = var.git_app_install_id
    authorizer_credential {
      oauth_token_secret_version = google_secret_manager_secret_version.github_token_secret_version.id
    }
  }
  depends_on = [google_secret_manager_secret_iam_policy.policy]
}

resource "google_cloudbuildv2_repository" "note_repository" {
  project           = var.gcp_project_id
  location          = var.gcp_region
  name              = "note-rest-api2"
  parent_connection = google_cloudbuildv2_connection.github_connection.name
  remote_uri        = var.git_uri
}


resource "google_cloudbuild_trigger" "note_app_backend_trigger" {
  location = var.gcp_region
  name     = "note-app-backend"
  filename = "cloudbuild.yaml"
  project  = var.gcp_project_id
  repository_event_config {
    repository = google_cloudbuildv2_repository.note_repository.id
    push {
      branch = "^test$"
    }
  }
}

Please somebody help, what Iam I doing wrong!
I expect a GCP cloud build trigger to be created using terraform

Not a Terraform dev. Can you try applying your plan with TF_LOG=TRACE (per Debugging) to see whether you can get Terraform to report the underlying REST API call? That may help you diagnose the issue. And/Or google_cloudbuild_trigger maps to projects.triggers.create which permits you to try the underlying REST method in the browser. You could try replicating the behavior there to uncover the "invalid argument"

I guess these changes are enforced and now you have to specify service account while creating a Cloud Build Trigger.
Inshort try using:
resource "google_cloudbuild_trigger" "note_app_backend_trigger" {
   ...
   service_account = google_service_account.cloudbuild_service_account.id
   ...
}

To Learn more refer:

https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/configure-user-specified-service-accounts
https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/cloud-build-service-account


Works for me with service_account = "projects/${var.project_id}/serviceAccounts/"

Thank you @FredKlein projects/{PROJECT_ID}/serviceAccounts/{ACCOUNT_ID_OR_EMAIL}  worked for me !!!

I know I'm late to the party, but in my case, I set up the trigger and then realized I had missed adding the service account.
When I tried assigning the service account like this: service_account = var.service_account_email, it failed with the error below:
Error: Error updating Trigger "projects/projectid/locations/us-west1/triggers/triggerid": googleapi: Error 400: Request contains an invalid argument.
│
│   with module.cloud_build.google_cloudbuild_trigger.tf_cloud_build,
│   on modules\cloud-build\main.tf line 1, in resource "google_cloudbuild_trigger" "tf_cloud_build":
│    1: resource "google_cloudbuild_trigger" "tf_cloud_build" {
│
╵
task: Failed to run task "apply": exit status 1

Then @FredKlein solution helped me to fix the issue, as format has to be projects/{PROJECT_ID}/serviceAccounts/{ACCOUNT_ID_OR_EMAIL}I tried reading the service account using data, as I already had one created, and then assigned it as shown below
data "google_service_account" "service_account" {
  account_id = var.service_account_email
}

resource "google_cloudbuild_trigger" "tf_cloud_build" {
  location                      = var.trigger_region
  name                          = var.trigger_name
  ...

  service_account               = data.google_service_account.service_account.id
}

data.google_service_account.service_account.id outputs the service account as shown below
projects/myprojectid/serviceAccounts/serviceaccountname@projectid.iam.gserviceaccount.com
